# C# ClickOnce installer - dynamic deployment path

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I've set up a ClickOnce installer which auto updates machines on a LAN and is working very well - however what would be great is if we could have the application deployment directory be dynamic, and specific to each machine (what we'd hope do is have a database table with the machine name and a deployment path).

Is this possible in ClickOnce? I.e. is it possible to use a different path to the manifest? I'm happy to check for updates after application start, rather than before.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this link http://briannoyes.net/2005/09/29/on-demand-updates-with-clickonce/

Comment: This link also might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699336.aspx